# Defining 3 by 3 matrix in Isabelle

Tags: matrix, isabelle

I am a beginner in using Isabelle for formal prove. I have to do multiplication between vector and 3 by 3 matrix.

Right now, I am able to define 3 element vector using this command

```
'consts x_vec :: "('a::real_vector) set ⇒ ('a ⇒ real×real×real) ⇒ bool"'
```

My question is how to define 3 by 3 matrix. The matrix that I need to working on is inertial matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite advanced Matrix library in the [Archive of Formal Proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Matrix.shtml).

It is particularly nice, because different matrix dimensions are covered by a uniform type scheme, with predicates for subspaces as in mathematics.